# Regex disallow characters from anywhere in string that has capture groups

Tags: regex

With the `Accept` [Http Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept), I have created the following regex string to validate the value of the header:

`^(([^\/]+[\/][^\/;,]+)(;q[ ]*=[ ]*[0-9][.][0-9])?([,][ ]*)?)+$`

Whilst this works for the different examples of valid header inputs (such as (single input): `text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml;q=0.9, image/webp, */*;q=0.8`), the header is a `CORS safelisted request header`, meaning that the header has an additional restriction: there is a set of characters that can't be in the value: `():<>?@[\]{}, 0x00-0x1f (except 0x09), 0x7f`.

So I tried to just disallow the `:` by putting `[^:]*` at the start or end of the regex string, with no effect. Is this syntax right, and if so where do I need to put it in order for it to apply to the entire string?

If the regex string is just `^[^:]*$`, then it disallows `:` anywhere in the string, so I'm not sure if for the header example  it isn't working due to capture groups? I haven't a huge amount of experience with regex. I will be implementing the regex into Python 3.9.

Answer (score 0):

Based on RFC-7231 at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2, each media type also accepts optional `key=value` parameters besides the `q=0.7`. Here is a more comprehensive test case to covers this:

```
text/*, text/plain, text/plain;format=flowed, text/html;level=1, text/html;level=2;q=0.4, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml;q=0.9, image/webp, */*;q=0.1
```

This regex tests for RFC compliance of the `Accept` value:

```
/^(?!.*[():<>?@\[\\\]{}\x00-\x08\x0a-\x1f\x7f])\s*[^\/]+\/[^,;]+(;\s*[^=]+(?<!\bq)=[^,;]+)*(;\s*q=[01](\.\d{1,3})?)?(,\s*[^\/]+\/[^,;]+(;\s*[^=]+(?<!\bq)=[^,;]+)*(;\s*q=[01](\.\d{1,3})?)?)*\s*$/
```

Same over multiple lines for readability (not a valid regex) :

```
/^(?!.*[():<>?@\[\\\]{}\x00-\x08\x0a-\x1f\x7f])
  \s*[^\/]+\/[^,;]+(;\s*[^=]+(?<!\bq)=[^,;]+)*(;\s*q=[01](\.\d{1,3})?)?
(,\s*[^\/]+\/[^,;]+(;\s*[^=]+(?<!\bq)=[^,;]+)*(;\s*q=[01](\.\d{1,3})?)?)*
\s*$/
```

Explanation:

- `^` - anchor to start of string
- `(?!.*[():<>?@\[\\\]{}\x00-\x08\x0a-\x1f\x7f])` - negative lookahead that tests for any of the invalid characters: greedy `.*` match up to `[...]` character class
- `\s*` - scan over optional whitespace
- `[^\/]+\/[^,;]+` - scan over 1+ chars, a `/`, and anything up to `,` or `;`, e.g. a media type, such as `text/plain`
- `(` ... `)*` - scan over optional `key=value` pattern, zero to multiple times:

  - `;\s*` - scan over `;` separator, and optional whitespace
  - `[^=]+(?<!\bq)` - scan over anything up to `=`, but not a `q`
  - `=` - scan over `=`
  - `[^,;]+` - scan over anything up to `,` or `;`
- `(` ... `)?` - scan over optional `q=1` or `q=0.001` pattern:

  - `;\s*` - scan over `;` separator, and optional whitespace
  - `q=[01]` - scan over `q=0` or `q=1`
  - `(\.\d{1,3})?` - followed by optional `.` and 1 to 3 digits (based on RFC)
- the first media type is covered up to this point
- `(` ... `)*` - scan over optional (zero to multiple) additional media types:

  - `,\s*` - scan over `,` separator, and optional whitespace
  - followed by same pattern as above to: scan for media type, scan for optional `key=value` patterns separated by `;`, scan for optional `q=...` pattern
- `\s*` - scan over optional whitespace
- `$` - anchor string at the end

Comment: @SamG101: Any questions? Does this fit your needs?

Comment: @SamG101: Care to accept the answer? Help can go both ways.

Comment: @SamG101: to appreciate the time people spend helping you, you can accept an acceptable answer. See gray check mark next to the question.

Answer (score -1):

You can put a negative look-ahead at the start of your regex:

`(?!.*[():<>?@\[\\\]{},\x00-\x08\x0a-\x1f\x7f])`

Comment: Fixed that typo